# How to add custom images and scale them to the SearXNG homepage?

Tags: docker-compose, searxng

I looked up ways to add a custom image to the homepage of SearXNG homepage but, the image which was being displayed was EXTREMELY small how can I scale this image to its actual size? Does it have to be in a specific aspect ratio to be properly displayed?

I am using docker with SearXNG by the way